# Uncountable number of functions representable by programs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability

I was reading an old thread here and came across an interesting [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/55522). I was familiar with the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), however it never dawned on me that there can only be countably infinite computer programs and this got me thinking.

Obviously all the functions $$x^n$$ can be implemented as computer programs. But so too couldn't all the functions $$x^{{n_1}^{{n_2}^{{n_3}^{...}}}}$$ where $$n_k \in (0..9)$$ Of course each of these would take a near infinitely long time to run but it would still *exist* computationally and be iterable. Correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't this imply there are uncountably infinite computer programs?

The argument I am hearing is it'd be impossible because you'd have to hardcode an infinite number of characters but I don't feel this is valid because much like the argument for the uncountability of the reals you can always create a unique program by adding another exponent much like how you could always a create a unique real by adding a digit.

Comment: That isn't a function. What does it evaluate to for $x=2$ and $n_i=2$ for all $i$?

Comment: @DanRust You can evaluate for arbitrarily large $i$ though, correct? No matter how large $i$ is you can evaluate it for $i+1$ obviously for $i = /infty$ you can't evaluate it.

Comment: Then it's not a function. A function takes in one value and outputs another. This does not do that.

Comment: It would though it would take in $2$ and give $2^{2^{2^{2^{...}^2}}}$

Comment: So your power tower is always finite?

Comment: @DanRust you can always construct a power tower larger than your previous power tower, so wouldn't that imply that it's infinite? As the set of power towers it's totally unbounded

Comment: You're talking nonsense. I think you need to brush up on some basic set theory terminology and theory.

Comment: @DanRust how am I talking nonsense? For every power tower with $n$ exponents there exists one with $n+1$ exponents

Comment: unbounded sets can happily be countably infinite. If I get you correctly, your set is $$\{x^{n_1^{\cdots^{n_k}}}\mid x,k \in \mathbb N, n_1,\ldots n_k \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$ This is a countable set.

Comment: @DanRust Can't I create a bijection between that and R? ${n_1}.{n_2}{n_3}...{n_k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: No, because each sequence of $n_i$s for any particular element is a finite string. You can't code any particular real number with an infinite decimal expansion in that way.

Comment: @DanRust Ah okay I see. I guess where my train of thought was taking me was that the *limit* of possible computer programs was uncountable. Akin to $\mathbb{Q} \in \mathbb{R}$ as opposed to $\mathbb{N}$. Perhaps some completion of all programs exists? I will probably think about it more.

Comment: @DanRust Is the set of decidable problems dense in the set of undecidable problems?

Comment: Depends on the topology you're putting on the set of problems....

Comment: But the intuitive idea is rather the opposite: the proportion of problems that can be expressed on $n$ which are decidable characters tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by $\ldots$ in $x^{{n_1}^{{n_2}^{{n_3}^{...}}}}$.  If that's a finite tower, it's just the same as $x^n$ for some suitable $n$.
If it's an infinite tower of arbitrary $n_i$'s, whatever that means, then no, you can't implement more than countably many different ones.

Comment: You can always construct a larger power tower though.. So for $$x^{{n_1}^{{n_2}^{{n_3}^{{...}^{n_k}}}}$$ you can construct one $$x^{{n_1}^{{n_2}^{{n_3}^{{...}^{n_k+1}}}}$$

Comment: So what?  If your tower is finite, that's still $x^n$ for some $n$.